# Disable HotKeys When Typing - VB6

Tags: vb6, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut, hotkeys

In my VB6 program, I have tons of hotkeys such as X, A, D... ETC . I also have a chat system in it, where everytime I use the characters X or A it will do the actions of those hotkeys. For example, if X was to close the application (not that it really does), when I am typing "fiXing" into my chat textbox, it will close the application. Can anyone tell me how to disable the hotkeys when typing EXCEPT the Enter Key?

thanks,

Kevin

Comment: Let's back up a bit.  You make it sound as though you have the hotkeys working already and just want to suppress their function while typing in a TextBox.  Do you have them working yet?  Can you add the relevant code to your question so we can get a better understanding of the problem?

Comment: Well I have a ton -_-. Like all the F1 F2... etc keys, and some of the enter, x, shift ... keys as well. These all implement in a game I am creating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the chat `TextBox`'s `GotFocus` event set a flag to disable your hotkeys.  Then re-enable them in the `TextBox`'s `LostFocus` event.

I don't know how you trap your hotkeys, but the code to set the flag is pretty simple:

```
Private suppressHotkeys As Boolean

Private Sub txtChat_GotFocus()
  suppressHotkeys = True
End Sub

Private Sub txtChat_LostFocus()
  suppressHotkeys = False
End Sub
```

Then in the code that traps the hotkeys, just check the flag:

```
If (Not suppressHotkeys) Then
  //process hotkey
End If
```

Comment: Ok.. I am still bewildered by the code you just posted... :/. I don't get it.. In the If statement do I put in the code where it involves the hotkeys?

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be better to use a key combination for your hot keys. It is more common to press say <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>. You would test for them in either the KeyDown or KeyUp events.

```
If KeyCode = vbKeyX And (Shift And vbCtrlMask = vbCtrlMask) Then
    ' Do something
End If
```